# Finding Closest Matching Value using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Consider a markup such as

```
<select id="blah">
  <option value="3">Some text</option>
  <option value="4">Some text</option>
  <option value="8">Some text</option> // <---- target this tag based on value 7
  <option value="19">Some text</option>
</select>
```

Suppose I have a value with me, say 7. Is it possible to target the option tag whose `value` attribute is closest to 7 which, in this case, would be `<option value="8">`?

I'm aware of `^` which means starting with and `$` which means ending with and was hoping if there is something like this to find the closest match for a given value.

Comment: Are you only looking for the closest highest value? Eg, you've got `6`, would `5` be valid, or `7`?

Comment: Could be highest or lowest...it wont matter. I just want to target that element and append another option tag after or before it

Comment: Are the options sorted by value?

Comment: Yes they are sorted in the ascending order

Comment: @undefined That is appending it as the last element.

Comment: If `4` and `8` are options and `5` is searched for, is `8` (closest larger) an acceptable output?

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for all those answers. Let me test each of them individually. @JanDvorak 4 would be a better match and it is more closer to 5 than 8

Comment: @asprin then ignore those answers where I've commented `I don't think "closest greater" is a correct interpretation` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GNNHy/

```
var $tmpOption = $('<option value="7">Some text 7</option>');
$("#blah").append($tmpOption);
var my_options = $("#blah option");
my_options.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (parseInt(a.value,10) > parseInt(b.value,10)) return 1;
    else if (parseInt(a.value,10) < parseInt(b.value,10)) return -1;
    else return 0
})

$("#blah").empty().append( my_options );
```

Comment: Perfect! Append and then sort! The logic was so simple and yet I missed it. +1 and accepted

Answer (score 3):

How about a recursion? It will find the closest value:

**[JS-BIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/erekus/2/edit)**

```
function getClosest(val, ddl, increment){
  if(ddl.find('option[value="'+val+'"]').length){
      return val;
  }
  else
    try{
      if(increment)
    return getClosest(++val, ddl, increment);
      else
        return getClosest(--val, ddl, increment);
    }
  catch(err){
    return -1;
  }
}

function findClosest(val, ddl){
   var larger = getClosest(val, ddl, true);
   var smaller = getClosest(val, ddl, false);
  if(larger == smaller == -1)
    return -1;
  else if (larger == -1)
    return smaller;
  else if (smaller == -1 )
    return larger;

  if(larger - val > val - smaller)
    return smaller;
  else
    return larger
}
```

Comment: At this point your answer is way longer than mine. How come? :-)

Comment: Mmm. I think I'm doing it the hard way

Answer (score 1):

Yes just substract your value (7) with the option values(use each function)...the value with the minimum positive outcome will be your targeted option. I hope you will have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is perhaps the good old linear search (you can do binary, but it's more tricky than usual):

```
var target;
var $options;

var best=Infinity;
var bestAt;

$options.each(function(){
  var error = this.value - target;
  error = error>0 ? error : -error;
  if(error<=best){
    best=error;
    bestAt=this;
  }
})

//return $(bestAt);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery I would do something like

```
$(function () {
        // comes from somewhere
        var val = 7;

        var sortByDifference = $("#blah option").sort(function (opt1, opt2) {
            return Math.abs(parseInt($(opt1).val()) - val) - Math.abs(parseInt($(opt2).val()) - val);
        });

        alert($(sortByDifference[0]).val());
    });
```

In sortByDifference you have all values sorted by how close they are to your value. The routine returns the closest greater or lower and doesn't require the options to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
function findClosest(num){
    var select = document.getElementById('blah');
    var options = select.options;
    var dif = Infinity;
    var index;
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        var newdif = Math.abs(parseInt(options[i].value) - num);
        if(newdif < dif){
             dif = newdif;
             index = i;
        }
    }
    select.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: What's `9007199254740992`? It smells terrible :-)

Comment: Note that the smallest number such that (x+1 == x) is not the best infinity. 2^53 smells bad.

Comment: lol..I +1 every answer posted to my question. Currently there is 15 sec cap between comments. So it's taking time to comment on each answer