# Select closest value in select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

From an API I got 'times' and that 'times' I put into select box like:

```
<select id="time">
  <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
  <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
  <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
  <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option> /// ETC
</select>
```

I want to show 20:00:00 as default time so I simply write jquery code:

```
$('#time').val('20:00:00');
```

The problem is because API don't return me each time 20:00:00 as option so I need to choose some other time, so How I can select with jquery the closest time to 20:00:00 so etc. how to select 21:00:00 if 20:00:00 is not in select box ?

Comment: Would it be better to add missing times as options?

Comment: no, I need to show what API return me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Closest Matching Value using jQuery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255698/finding-closest-matching-value-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find all the options equal to or greater than the desired time, and then select the first one, provided the list is ordered already.

```js
var time = '20:00:00';

function changeTime ( value ) {
  //select all the options and filter them
  $('#time option').filter(function(index, element){
      //return just the ones that have a value equal to or
      //greater than our desired time
      return element.value >= value;
    }).eq(0).prop('selected', true); //select the first one
}

changeTime( time );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="time">
  <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
  <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
  <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option> /// ETC
</select>
```

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH! VERY ELEGANT SOLUTION!